# What are 'payable' state variables?

Tags: addresses, payable, state-variable

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/solidity-by-example.html#simple-open-auction

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.22;    
contract SimpleAuction {
    address payable public beneficiary;
```

What exactly does `payable` mean here? Are there non-payable addresses? Should one always explicitly declare state variables of type address like so?

Answer (score 1):

A payable address means it can receive Eth.
It is similar to a payable modifier. The functions which have a payable modifier can send and receive eth.

```
payable(address).transfer(amount)
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried to compile the entire code. It doesn't go past that line. Payable shouldn't be declared with the name variable else you are getting

> 'Expected identifier but got 'payable' at address payable public beneficiary;'

I assume it's just an error. If you remove 'payable' in line 7 and line 35 the code works fine, else it doesn't compile.

Comment: I find it weird, that an example in the documentation is wrong. However, it is possible that it is also a deprecated feature .. I will take a look to the GitHub repository